# What is an antonym for 'one-to-one'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, mathematics

I am writing a perspective for a general medical science audience. The following adapted figure will be included in the publication:[image]

The figure title appearing in the legend includes the following sentence,

> Figure 1: Schematic illustrating the non- one-to-one relationship
> between hypotheses, process models, and statistical models.

The only thesaurus with an entry for 'one-to-one' that I have found is WordNet. They provide only "matched" as a 'similar to' entry (not quite a synonym). The word I'm looking for should refer to matching relationships that are **not** one-to-one. I would also accept any answer that contains any true synonyms that could lead to an antonym. Or, is simply "non-one-to-one" the way to go? It's not the most aesthetically pleasing option.

Comment: This can't be answered well without a specific context. For example, in the context of "one to one instruction" (ie when teaching), I would suggest "classroom instruction". Please add your context so your question can be answered.

Comment: I doubt there's a word that encompasses all the relationships that aren't one-one. "Non-isomorphic" is on the way there, but I think it has some additional connotations that you're not looking for.

Comment: A group meeting is not 1-to-1.

Comment: I have added additional context for my use case. @Laurel

Comment: Multiple relationships?

Comment: @user888379 "Non-isomorphic" is a good idea, and has use in graph theory. However, this paper is a primer for non-specialists, so may not unfortunately be a good match for the audience (which I have edited my question to include context, such as intended audience).

Comment: one-to-many or many-to-many are the obvious terms. You'll have to work out which applies.

Comment: @WS2 "multiple relationships" is an interesting idea. 'Relationships' is likely too broad, but modifying it to something like, "may pair with multiple models" might work. Might be worth submitting as an answer?

Comment: @Flaunk Don't use 'non-isomorphic', it does not apply to this situation at all. You would avoid making terminological errors by just making your caption "The relationships between hypotheses, process models, and statistical models". This avoids misusing  the terminology.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, your right, even the application to graph theory isn't quite right. Your suggestion to avoid using any terms would avoid confusion, but it would not label the main point the schematic is illustrating. Also, to clarify, do you also feel "non-one-to-one"  would be confusing?

Comment: @Flaunk 'non-one-to-one' would be ungainly in any context. Here it is definitely confusing.  The main point is the picture of the relation, which says so much more than being improperly shoehorned into a single word.

Comment: As Stuart said, there's "one-to-many."  There's also "many-to-one."  Usually people say something like, "It's not a one-to-one relationship."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the term ***non-exclusive*** to describe one-to-many or many-to-one relationships. An exclusive relationship is between exactly two members, neither one can have relationships between any other items aside from their one exclusive partner. Overall, this will capture that any element can pair with more than one other element. None of the relationships shown in the diagram are exclusive, as every pair of relationship partners has at least one partner pairing with a third element.

Changing the caption to

> Schematic illustrating the non-exclusive relationships between
> hypotheses, process models, and statistical models.

should make it clear that each of the items can associate with more than one of the others.

Comment: This assumes that *exclusive* is synonymous with *one-to-one*, but (considered on its own, apart from a context that might narrow down the range of possible interpretations) it simply means that others are excluded, without implying that only one item is included.

Comment: @jsw29 An exclusive *relationship* is one-to-one. You cannot have any kind of relationship that has only one member and no partner.

Comment: @jsw29 This is true, and a good point. I guess you could call this a context-dependent antonym (or is that basically what an 'indirect antonym' is)? If someone does come up with a solid direct antonym, I will accept that answer instead. For now, I will leave this answer as accepted because I did not specify whether the antonym needed to be direct or indirect, and this answer does satisfy my use case.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, yes, but one-many and many-many relationships can all be exclusive. Consider 'the courses whose numbers begin with 3 or 4 are open exclusively to graduate and upper-level undergraduate students'. There are many such courses and many such students, but the relationship is exclusive, in that it excludes other students.

Comment: Regardless, there is also a relative sense of the word "exclusive," as when used in the phrase 'mutually exclusive.' Multiple non-one-to-one pairings could be said to be mutually exclusive. There is likely a fair amount of ambiguity in drawing the line between direct and indirect antonyms.

Comment: @jsw29 Interesting point, I agree it's not a perfect antonym in all cases. I'll note there's a couple of definitions of exclusive, it can mean either "not admitting others" or "restricted in a particular way". For example, "I have exclusive access to the beach" means only I can access the beach, but "I belong to an exclusive club" just means that many others are excluded, not that I am the only member. Exclusivity can also imply directionality depending on phrasing - a club open exclusively to members only admits members, but does not imply those members cannot go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [multifaceted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multifaceted). There are multiple angles or facets to consider when reviewing the statistical models and processes, and the outcomes are not one-to-one for a given input or set.

Answer (score 0):

This schematic illustrates several one-to-many relationships between hypotheses, process models, and statistical models.

Relationships in databases can be one-to-one, one-to-many or some combinations.